# Generalizing disjointness

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, order-theory, universal-algebra

The following definition generalizes set-theoretic disjointess:

> **Definition 0. (Autonomy).** Given a Lawvere theory $\mathsf{T}$, a $\mathsf{T}$-algebra $X$, and an indexed family $S$ of subalgebras of $X$, call $S$ *autonomous* iff the obvious map $$\bigsqcup_{i:I} S_i \rightarrow X$$ is injective, where $I$ denotes the index set of $S$.
>
> (Also: [I'm searching for standardized terminology for this condition.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1395629/notation-terminology-for-independent-subspaces-subalgebras))

This can be generalized so that it makes sense inside any category equipped with a notion of "injective morphism" that has all small coproducts.

Anyway, I want to understand this order-theoretically. So define:

> **Definition 1. (Order-theoretic autonomy).** Given a complete lattice $L$ and an indexed family $s$ of elements of $L$, call $s$ *(order-theoretically) autonomous* iff the join function $$\prod_{i:I} \downarrow (s_i) \rightarrow L$$
>    is injective.
>
> (Notation: $\downarrow x$ is the lowerset generated by $x$, for any $x \in L$.)

Observe that (genuine) autonomy implies order-theoretic autonomy. Presumably, the converse doesn't hold.

> **Questions.**
>
> **Q0.** I'd like a counterexample to the backwards implication, or else a proof that it holds.
>
> **Q1.** Has anyone ever proposed a definition of "complete lattice equipped with a notion of autonomy" such that for every algebraic structure $X$, the complete lattice of subalgebras of $X$ is canonically equipped with a notion of autonomy as per Definition 0?

Comment: +1 for this nice (and natural) question!

Comment: @DominicvanderZypen, thanks for the kind words :)